# Visual Studio Theme Customize Colors

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm wondering if there is a reference manual of some kind which would indicate what items in the "Customize Colors" menu correspond with items on the Visual Studio IDE.

For instance, here's the Class View with one of the items highlighted (light green on white):
[image: Class View]

And here's a view of the spillover tabs section (Black text on dark gray):
[image]

My issue is that the list of items to change in the "Customize Colors" dialog (as shown in image one) is extremely long and I'm having a hard time corresponding the names to actual items in the Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: if you want to change your colors the use [this](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/20cd93a2-c435-4d00-a797-499f16402378)

Comment: This website (http://studiostyl.es/) can be used to customize the scheme based on elements.  It features a clickable UI.